# Kafka state store returns null when using Avro

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We have a kTable where we map the values and materialize to KeyValueStore using the following code:

```
    @Bean
    public KTable<String, CancelEvent> kTable(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder,
                                          ValueMapper<CancelEvent, CancelEvent> mapper,
                                          SpecificAvroSerde<CancelEvent> serde) {

      return kStreamBuilder
            .table(properties.getProperty("topics.cancel"), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serde))
            .mapValues(mapper, Materialized.as("cancel-event-store"));

    }
```

And mapper code:

```
    @Override
    public CancelEvent apply(CancelEvent value) {

      if (value.getData().getCancelled()) {
        return null;
      }

      return value;

    }
```

We use Avro for serialization and deserialization. When we try to query the `state store` with a key, it always returns `null`.

Code for querying the state store:

```
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, CancelEvent> store = streamsFactory.getKafkaStreams()
            .store("cancel-event-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

    CancelEvent event = store.get(queryEvent.getMeta().getId().toString());
```

`event` is always `null`. While debugging, I iterated through the `keyValuestore`, and realized something is appened to the key (magic byte may be!). Please refer the image below

[image]

So, the question is how to query with key?

**Update 1**

```
    private Map<String, Object> kStreamsConfigsProperties() {
    final Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app.name" + new Date().getTime());

    config.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, properties.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
    config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, properties.getProperty("spring.kafka.schema-registry"));

    config.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    config.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class.getName());
    config.put(DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());

    return config;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the data in KTable if value contains null or data?

Comment: Yes, it has values and its not null

Comment: What `Serde` are specified in you config? Because `Materialized` does not specify serdes explicitly, the config ones will be used. Side remark: why not use `KTable#filter()`?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sac, I have updated the question with config

Comment: And how does `KTable#filter()` will solve the issue? I'm making the value as `null`, because it has to be considered `tombstone` message on certain criterial. Pleas correct me if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Using `#filter()` is just easier to read (and less code) that implementing filter logic within `mapValues()`.

Comment: The config looks ok. What key do you refer to with `and realized something is appened to the key`? The key that you pass into `store.get()`? What type is `queryEvent` that you use there? Maybe `queryEvent.getMeta().getId().toString()` does something unexpected. What type does `getId()` return?

Comment: The issue is because of confluent's `kafka-avro-console-producer`. I was generating the event with console producer. Apparently it added something in front with the key. Thanks for the support.